# Best Android Scoped Storage option for my use case

Tags: android, scoped-storage

I have been trying to look for the best Scoped Storage solution for my use case for some time now. The use case is the following:

- Users can create their own designs in the app
- Those designs are saved as files in a custom directory on the storage of the device
- When the user uninstalls the app, the files (designs) should remain on the phone, so that when they reinstall the app their designs will still be there

So now with Scoped Storage on Android SDK >= 30, we cannot access the external data directories anymore without explicitly asking permission to access a folder.

Right now I have an implementation using ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE. That works, but it requires the user to pick which folder to use as our base folder. From an UX perspective this is not great.

Is there another option where files remain on the device after the app gets uninstalled? I have tried a bit with MediaStore and app attribution, but it seems that after uninstall the files are not attributed to our app anymore.

Thanks for any help! If ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE is the only way, than I will go for that option.

Comment: MediaStore has an advantage of not requiring folder selection, but if the app is uninstalled and later reinstalled, then you have a very awkward UX to let the user work with the existing files. The API itself is also more limited and flaky with things like subfolder creation or non-standard filetypes.

Comment: The other thing to consider is nobody knows how well tested the MediaStore implementation will be across all the different handsets. I've seen a LOT of issues with Storage Access Framework, especially pre-Android 11.

Comment: Thanks, for your reply. Do you mean that there are both issues with SAF and MediaStore across different handsets?

Comment: Yes, for sure. It's better on Android 11 but I still see many issues with the new MediaStore scoped storage, and some of them are by design. There are also many open bugs: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues?q=componentid:190923%2B%20Scoped%20storage. Also check "MediaStore" and "Storage Access Framework".

Comment: Thanks (and sorry for the late reply), just found out that WearOS 3.0 does not have an activity to handle OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE, although it's API 30 based. Could that be true?

Comment: Yes that makes sense. Even on Android 11 there are some devices that don't support OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE and you need to have a fallback for that. For Wear OS it may make more sense to just use context.getFilesDir() or getExternalFilesDirs().

Comment: Yeah could use context.getFilesDir() or getExternalFilesDirs() but that would mean that the files will be deleted when the app gets uninstalled, which could be very annoying for users.